# Specify helper function that's used by another helper function inside a class

Tags: python, pandas, class

Update to question:

I want to include a helper function in my class that uses another helper function that's only used within one of the methods of the class.  Using `@staticmethod` and self.func_name is what I'd do if I had one staticmethod.. However, if I want to call another staticmethod from a staticmethod and specify that using self.helper_func, I get an 'name 'self' is not defined' error.

To give you some context, the reason I'm doing this is because in my actual use case, I'm working with a list of grouped dataframes.  Then within that outer apply statement, I then iterate through sets of specific columns in each grouped dataframe and apply the actual function.  So the outer helper function is just an apply over the groups in the grouped dataframes, and it then calls the inner helper that performs manipulations on groups of columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class DataManipulation():

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @staticmethod
    def helper_func(const):
        return const
    
    @staticmethod
    def add_constant(var):
        res = var+self.helper_func(5)
        return res


    def manipulate_data(self):
        res = self.data.apply(add_constant)
        return res

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(4), 'b': np.arange(4)})
data_manip = DataManipulation(test_df)
data_manip.manipulate_data()
```

Comment: use `self.add_constant`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how can static `@staticmethod` access `self`

[Static method can be called without creating an object or instance.](https://pythonbasics.org/static-method/)
So what will be `self` when `staticmethod` is called before creating any object?
PS. Well that's my opinion, I may be wrong (I am new to python, that's how it was in C / C++ / Java).
Maybe you need to call `DataManipulation.helper_func(5)` instead of `self.helper_func(5)`.